# SPOJ Factorial Problem

Tags: java

I am trying to develop code for SPOJ factorial problem number 11. The following is my code

```
import java.math.*; 
import java.io.*;
public class Problem11 {

/**
 * Count the number of zeroes at the end of 
 * the factorial value of a number.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 int numOfInputs=0;
 numOfInputs=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
 BigInteger nextNum[]=new BigInteger[numOfInputs];
 BigInteger factValue[]=new BigInteger[numOfInputs];

 //Get all the numbers to be computed
 for(int count=0;count<numOfInputs;count++)
 {
    nextNum[count]=new BigInteger(br.readLine());
 }

 //Obtain the factorial value for each number
 for(int count=0;count<numOfInputs;count++)
 {
     factValue[count]=getFact(nextNum[count]);
 }

 //Obtain the number of trailing zeroes
 for(int count=0;count<numOfInputs;count++)
 {
     //System.out.println(factValue[count]);
     System.out.println(getZeroes(factValue[count]));

 }
}


public static String getZeroes(BigInteger num) 
 {
    int numOfZeroes=0;
    while(num.remainder(BigInteger.TEN).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
    {
        num=num.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
        numOfZeroes++;
    }
    return String.valueOf(numOfZeroes);
 }



public static BigInteger getFact(BigInteger num) 
{
    BigInteger factorial=BigInteger.ONE;    
    if(num.equals(0))
    {
      return (BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    }
    else
    {
        int count=1;
        while((BigInteger.valueOf(count).compareTo(num))<=0)        
        {               
            factorial=factorial.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(count));
            count++;
        }
    }

    return factorial;

}

}
```

The code works fine for numbers up to 5 digits with small delay and for the last number 
`8735373` it is taking too much time, if I submit my solution, the judge shows compilation error.. I am unable to figure out whats the error. Please have a look at my code and help me to trace the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might look at this method for finding [the number of trailing zeros in *n*!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_zeros#Factorial).

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int result = 0;
            for (int d = 5; d <= n; d *= 5) {
                result += n / d;
            }
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not the fastest one there, but it's a start.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach (naive: counting the real factorial value and then counting the zeros manually) would NEVER pass no matter how. Take a look at the extreme case (i.e. upper limit of the factorial, I don't even think the given memory limit is enough to compute it). Look at the problem from different way, think what the real problem is, that's the art of problem solving ;)

Hint: what can produce and add more 0s to the end of a number, specifically by multiplication?

Comment: Thanks for the immediate help, can you confirm me whether my approach to obtain the factorial value is fine, so that I would think a while for obtaining the number of zeroes in the value?

Comment: You don't need to obtain the value of the factorial :)

Comment: As Jesus said, no. You don't need it, you just need to get the factors that causes 0. Another hint: the solution's complexity is O(1) :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is it should be `public class Main`

Also your code will get TLE, you must observe that brute force will never work on SPOJ. The way to solve this is to see an interesting pattern with powers of 5 and the number of zeroes at the end.

Comment: Oh! I am getting confused and too much excited, which portion of my code to change. Thank you very much for the reply. Could you please help me more to solve these kind of problems?

Comment: Brute Force = bad. Let me give you a little bit of a hint. Multiplying by what numbers adds 1 zero? So then n! contains as many zeroes (at the end) as there are factors of these numbers in n.

Comment: Now i am getting a run time error NZEC. I have changed the class name to Main. As for your approach I would get a zero if I multiply a number by 10. For example if `100!` the value is `93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000` and there are 24 zeroes. Please explain me the approach

Comment: 10 is not the only number, what if it ends in 2 and I multiply by 5? Also NZEC means your program crashed or threw up an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in C. We don't need to compute the exact factorial for this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 1000000
int xpn(int x, int n){
int prod=1;
while(n){
prod*=x;
n--;
}
return prod;
}
int trail(int x){
int numZero=0;
int i=1;
int k;
for(;x/xpn(5,i);i++){
numZero+=(x/xpn(5,i));
}
return numZero;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
#if 1
int n;
int num[MAX];
int zero[MAX];
scanf("%d",&n);
int count=n;
int i=0;
while(count){
scanf("%d",&num[i]);
zero[i]=trail(num[i]);
printf("%d\n",zero[i]);
i++;
count--;
}
#endif
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see you have been using BigInteger class of java. You don't need to compute factorial for this problem. It's an inefficient solution. Check out the tutorial http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_zeros#Factorial
and my implementation in C for reference. 
I hope you will be able to code it in Java then.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = s.nextInt();
        while (t-->0){
            int n = s.nextInt();
            int count = 0;
            while(n>0){
                count +=n/5;
                n/=5;
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }

    }
}
```

This solution will work absolutely fine.
Let me explain it.
When you refer to quantitative aptitude there is a short formula for calculating the number of trailing zeroes for any factorial number. Divide the number directly by 5 and start adding quotient and then divide quotient with 5 and again add until the value start giving constant quotient. Refer to below example. If you don't even understand refer to quantitative aptitude from any source.

e.g.

```
1. 60!  60/5 = 12, 12/5 = 2, add all the quotient i.e equals to 14.
2. 500! 500/5 = 100, 100/5 = 20, 20/5 = 4, ans = 124.
```