# When taking input in programming competitions, what do I do to stop the scanner from reading input?

Tags: java, stdin

I have been in one competition before, and I have looked into another. But when in it, I realized I had no idea what to do about taking user input from a machine. When a normal human uses it, I know I can just quit by assigning keywords for that, but how would I handle that in a competition when it is piped into a machine which generates its own code to test mine? How do I write my code to break out of a while loop when I have no idea what the last input will be?

When looking at this in java:

```
while(sc.hasNext()){ /*code here. Breaks out when machine input is done*/}
```

I looked into it, and I came across this: "Read inputs from STDIN and output to STDOUT." When I clicked on the link for java, it gave me the wikipedia for the buffered reader or scanner, but gave no additional info but the example code I just gave.

Sample input:

```
2
2 5
3 4 8
```

Lets assume the first line is how many more lines to read. How do we know when to stop reading in each individual line, or do we just read the whole line?

Comment: The question is so vague. You include absolutely no context. Are you asking how to break out of a while loop? Are you asking how to know when you've received the "complete" input? (if so, we'd need to know a lot more about the expected input). The question is just really not specific or clear at all.

Comment: I added my question, though it seemed implied. But I am not simply asking how to break out of a while loop. I want to know what do i do when I do not know what the last input will be. In competitions, they test your code in a test environment, not by people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some competition problems specify a [count](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/FCTRL/) that determines valid input, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6895871/230513).

Comment: @Andy his example link gives you exactly the same thing I did in pseudo code but in Java - we are all saying the same thing here... I don't think you need him to check your sample input... the answer is already here for you if you look for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(sc.hasNext() && !shouldStopReading){ /*code here*/}
```

or there is also...

```
while(sc.hasNext()){ /*code here*/ if (shouldStopReading) { break; } }
```

**To respond to your edit:**

> Sample input: 2 2 5 3 4 8
>
> Lets assume the first line is how many more lines to read. How do we
>   know when to stop reading in each individual line, or do we just read
>   the whole line?

A "line" typically ends in a Carriage Return / Line Feed combination on Windows, or simply a Line Feed on Mac / Unix / Linux. You can just look for these characters to delimit the lines.

Usually there are functions specifically for reading a "line".

Your example seems pretty straight forward. As pseudo-code:

```
String lineCountString = ReadLine();
int lineCount = StringToInt(lineCountString);
for (i from 0 to lineCount - 1)
     String aLine = ReadLine();
     DoSomethingWithEachLine(aLine);
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to a http://www.go-hero.net/jam/, which has a recored of all the entered solutions for Google Code Jam.

You can search by language and see many examples of how input files are read.

You'll probably get a better idea of the different ways of doing this by looking at examples.